# How to display form data on the same page when they are valid only?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, form-submit

I am working on a simple assignment which is creating a form that takes grades and name and then displays each grade separate with its value and the final grade. I have created this without using form element and it worked totally fine, but the problem was the validity such as if negative numbers are inserted, it'll still calculate. I have to change the code so it'll display validation message to the user to show that some values are not typed properly or missing, however, the program is not working properly as it'll display nothing. I deleted the form element out, so it'll still show the validation message but it'll also calculate empty fields and display the message. 
I created functions to call each other and to check before displaying but I still got an error. 
How would I be able to do so, when the user clicks submit it won't submit or display anything until it's all valid data? and then if it's all valid it'll display the results?
Here is my code I hope you guys can help.
P.s: My code has so many functions that I was testing out so please discard the mess and I hope you can help. 
Thank you!

```js
var x = 1;
var gradesArray = [];
var sum = 0;

var dict = [{
  grade: 94,
  message: ' is, A, excellent'
}, {
  grade: 90,
  message: ' is A-, great job'
}, {
  grade: 87,
  message: ' is B+, great'
}, {
  grade: 84,
  message: ' is, B, amazing'
}, {
  grade: 80,
  message: ' is, B-, study little more'
}, {
  grade: 77,
  message: ' is C+, you could do better'
}, {
  grade: 74,
  message: ' is C',
  70: ' is, C-'
}, {
  grade: 67,
  message: ' is D+'
}, {
  grade: 60,
  message: ' is D-'
}];


function gradeCheck(sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
    if (sum >= dict[i].grade) {
      return dict[i].message;
    } else if (sum < 60) {
      return ' F, its a fail';
    }
  }
}

function gradeCal() {
  const elemnts = document.querySelectorAll('.grade-calculator input[type=number]')
  //var sum = 0;
  var x = 1;
  for (let element of elemnts) {
    gradesArray[x] = Number(element.value);
    sum += Number(element.value);
    x++;
  }
  pageResults(sum);
  //return false;
}


function pageResults(sum) {
  for (var i = 1; i < gradesArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(gradesArray[i]);
    document.getElementById(i.toString()).innerHTML = (gradesArray[i]).toString();
  }

  var nameS = document.getElementById("name").value;
  document.getElementById("AG").innerHTML = nameS + " your grade is: " + (sum / 4) + "  " + gradeCheck((sum / 4));
  showResults();
}


function showResults() {
  let fp = document.getElementById('formPage');
  let rp = document.getElementById('result');

  if (fp.style.display == '') {
    fp.style.display = 'none';
    rp.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

/* function validateForm(event) {
           gradeCal();
       }
        //I created this function so it 
        function process(){
    
           var nameV = document.getElementById('name').value,
               errors = 0;
            
           for(var i=0; i<gradesArray.length; i++){
               i <= 4? (gradesArray[i] > 0) && (gradesArray[i] < 26) ? errors += 0: errors +=1 : gradesArray[i] > 0 && gradesArray[i] < 100? errors += 0 : errors +=1;
           }
           if(nameV =='' && errors > 0){
               event.preventDefault();

           }else{
               pageResults(sum);
           }
       }
        */
```

```html
<form>
  <p id='formPage' style="display:">
    <h2>Grade calculator</h2>
    <p class="form-example">
      <label for="name">Enter your name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="10" required pattern="[A-Z][A-Za-z' -]+">
    </p>
    <p class="grade-calculator">
      <h3>Insert assignment grades</h3>
      <p class="assignment-Grd">
        <label for="assignment">Enter your assignment grade: </label>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment1" id="inputSpace1" min="0" max="25" placeholder="First Assignment" required pattern="\d+">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment2" id="inputSpace2" min="0" max="25" placeholder="Second Assignment" required pattern="\d+">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment2" id="inputSpace3" min="0" max="25" placeholder="Third Assignment" required pattern="\d+">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment2" id="inputSpace4" min="0" max="25" placeholder="Fourth Assignment" required pattern="\d+">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="assignment">Enter midtem grade: </label>
        <input type="number" name="midterm" id="inputSpace5" min="0" max="100" placeholder="midterm grade" required pattern="\d+">
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="assignment">Enter Finam exam grade: </label>
        <input type="number" name="finalEx" id="inputSpace6" min="0" max="100" placeholder="final grade" required pattern="\d+">
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="assignment">Enter project grade: </label>
        <input type="number" name="finalProj" id="inputSpace7" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Project grade" required pattern="\d+">
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="form-example">
        <button id="submitB" onclick="gradeCal()">Submit</button>
        <button onclick="reset()">Cancel</button>
      </p>
    </p>
  </p>
</form>
<div id="result" style="display: none">
  <h3>The results</h3>
  <div>First Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="1"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Second Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="2"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Third Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="3"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Fourth Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="4"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Midterm Exam Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="5"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Final Exam Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="6"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Project Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="7"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Average Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="AG"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a small form validation library and i believe it could help solve your problem, check it out [here](https://github.com/kellyjoe256/js-form-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function as simple as this :

```
function validateGrade(inputBox) {
  if(inputBox.value<0) 
    inputBox.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Value cannot be less than 0";
}
```

And use the onchange event on each textbox:

```
onchange="validateGrade(this)"
```

Something like this:

```js
var x = 1;
var gradesArray = [];
var sum = 0;

var dict = [{
  grade: 94,
  message: ' is, A, excellent'
}, {
  grade: 90,
  message: ' is A-, great job'
}, {
  grade: 87,
  message: ' is B+, great'
}, {
  grade: 84,
  message: ' is, B, amazing'
}, {
  grade: 80,
  message: ' is, B-, study little more'
}, {
  grade: 77,
  message: ' is C+, you could do better'
}, {
  grade: 74,
  message: ' is C',
  70: ' is, C-'
}, {
  grade: 67,
  message: ' is D+'
}, {
  grade: 60,
  message: ' is D-'
}];


function gradeCheck(sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
    if (sum >= dict[i].grade) {
      return dict[i].message;
    } else if (sum < 60) {
      return ' F, its a fail';
    }
  }
}

function gradeCal() {
  const elemnts = document.querySelectorAll('.grade-calculator input[type=number]')
  //var sum = 0;
  var x = 1;
  for (let element of elemnts) {
    gradesArray[x] = Number(element.value);
    sum += Number(element.value);
    x++;
  }
  pageResults(sum);
  //return false;
}


function pageResults(sum) {
  for (var i = 1; i < gradesArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(gradesArray[i]);
    document.getElementById(i.toString()).innerHTML = (gradesArray[i]).toString();
  }

  var nameS = document.getElementById("name").value;
  document.getElementById("AG").innerHTML = nameS + " your grade is: " + (sum / 4) + "  " + gradeCheck((sum / 4));
  showResults();
}


function showResults() {
  let fp = document.getElementById('formPage');
  let rp = document.getElementById('result');

  if (fp.style.display == '') {
    fp.style.display = 'none';
    rp.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function validateGrade(inputBox) {
  if(inputBox.value<0) 
    inputBox.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Value cannot be less than 0";
}

/* function validateForm(event) {
           gradeCal();
       }
        //I created this function so it 
        function process(){
    
           var nameV = document.getElementById('name').value,
               errors = 0;
            
           for(var i=0; i<gradesArray.length; i++){
               i <= 4? (gradesArray[i] > 0) && (gradesArray[i] < 26) ? errors += 0: errors +=1 : gradesArray[i] > 0 && gradesArray[i] < 100? errors += 0 : errors +=1;
           }
           if(nameV =='' && errors > 0){
               event.preventDefault();

           }else{
               pageResults(sum);
           }
       }
        */
```

```css
.validity {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p id='formPage' style="display:">
    <h2>Grade calculator</h2>
    <p class="form-example">
      <label for="name">Enter your name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="10" required pattern="[A-Z][A-Za-z' -]+">
    </p>
    <p class="grade-calculator">
      <h3>Insert assignment grades</h3>
      <p class="assignment-Grd">
        <label for="assignment">Enter your assignment grade: </label>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment1" id="inputSpace1" min="0" max="25" placeholder="First Assignment" required pattern="\d+" onchange="validateGrade(this)">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment2" id="inputSpace2" min="0" max="25" placeholder="Second Assignment" required pattern="\d+" onchange="validateGrade(this)">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment2" id="inputSpace3" min="0" max="25" placeholder="Third Assignment" required pattern="\d+" onchange="validateGrade(this)">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="number" name="assignment2" id="inputSpace4" min="0" max="25" placeholder="Fourth Assignment" required pattern="\d+" onchange="validateGrade(this)">
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </p>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="assignment">Enter midtem grade: </label>
        <input type="number" name="midterm" id="inputSpace5" min="0" max="100" placeholder="midterm grade" required pattern="\d+" onchange="validateGrade(this)">
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="assignment">Enter Finam exam grade: </label>
        <input type="number" name="finalEx" id="inputSpace6" min="0" max="100" placeholder="final grade" required pattern="\d+" onchange="validateGrade(this)">
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="assignment">Enter project grade: </label>
        <input type="number" name="finalProj" id="inputSpace7" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Project grade" required pattern="\d+" onchange="validateGrade(this)">
        <span class="validity"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="form-example">
        <button id="submitB" onclick="gradeCal()">Submit</button>
        <button onclick="reset()">Cancel</button>
      </p>
    </p>
  </p>
</form>
<div id="result" style="display: none">
  <h3>The results</h3>
  <div>First Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="1"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Second Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="2"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Third Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="3"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Fourth Assignment:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="4"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Midterm Exam Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="5"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Final Exam Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="6"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Project Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="7"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Average Grade:
    <p class='gradeStyle' id="AG"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is great use but the problem still not solved because if you click submit without filling in the data it will still show the results in the bottom if scroll down. Tha't the main issue I have!